# Sort JSON NSDictionary into different order

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I want to plot a graph with this data (date against number of times something occurs). However, I first need to get the labels, which is the time, separated from the data to plot, which is the number below.

So in the end I need two different Arrays of data

How could I do that?

This is the following JSON:

```
(
    (
    20150712,
    10
),
    (
    20150713,
    15
),
    (
    20150714,
    12
),
    (
    20150715,
    11
),
    (
    20150716,
    45
),
    (
    20150717,
    12
),
    (
    20150718,
    6
)
)
```

PD: I know it is a bit tricky to understand, I hope you see my point (basically, just separate each type of data).

**EDIT:**

I tried listing all objects using `[NSDictionary allValues]` with no success.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Like parsing the JSON, iterating over the values and splitting them into the correct arrays?

Comment: That doesn't look like valid JSON.

Comment: @luk2302 - That is precisely what I am trying to do, but I am unable to split them into arrays...

Comment: @danielbeard - It is part of a JSON, but turning it to a ``NSDictionary`` and getting rid of other data with ``[NSDictionary objectsForKey:]`` I get that.

Comment: Parse it correctly to NSArray (of NSArray it seems), then you can sort it. What's the object you're currently logging?

Comment: @Larme - How can I sort it? I am logging ``NSDictionary *graphData = [json objectForKey:@"rows"]``. I don't really understand the question.

Comment: `graphData` seems to be a `NSArray` object to me, not a `NSDictionary`. There is no "Key/value" in it.

Comment: @Larme - Changing it to ``NSArray`` behaves the same way in this case. Still unable to split both sides... I thought that using ``NSDictionary`` would be easier :/

Comment: `NSMutableArray *datas1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; NSMutableArray *datas2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; for (int i =0; i < [graphData count]; i ++){NSArray *temp = graphData[i]; [datas1 addObject:temp[0]]; [datas2 addObject:temp[1]];}`?

Comment: @Larme - This worked perfectly fine. Exactly what I was looking for!!! Thank you! Would you like to publish this answer in order to mark it as an accepted solution?